# Using an exFAT usb drive with ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, mount, exfat

I was trying to insert my 128GB USB drive with movies into my Ubuntu 12.04LTS. It doesn't recognize the drive. Says it can't read the `exFAT` system.

Now I've been searching here and I found the following:

> You will need the package `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` to allow you to
>   read and write on `exFAT` drives:
>
> For Ubuntu 12.04
>
> Open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:
>
> ```
> To add the correct repository:
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
>
> To update your package list:
> sudo apt-get update
>
> To install fuse-exfat and exfat-utils packages:
> sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat exfat-utils
> ```
>
> Afterwards you just need to plug in the HDD and you're good to go.

---

The problem now is that my terminal says:

```
sudo: apt: command not found
```

Anyone knows why this error pops up and how to solve it?

I'm a total newbie in linux systems. Also know nothing about commands in terminal, always worked with the software center.

Comment: Just type `apt` in to a terminal, is it installed ? You should see  `Usage: apt [options] command` and some parameters if it is installed or `the program apt is not currently installed` if it is not found

Comment: "Problem now is that my terminal says sudo: apt: command not found" This seems wrong. The command is "apt-get" NOT "apt.

Comment: There is no need to add a PPA to install `fuse-exfat exfat-utils`.

Comment: @Pilot6- Those are in the backports repository for precise, probably the reason to add the ppa. You could add backports ... http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-backports/exfat-utils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly mis-typed the commands to run as none of those commands involved running apt.

If you need assistance with commands. paste the exact command you ran and the exact error message . You can copy-paste from the terminal.

The commands you need to run are (without the explanation)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat exfat-utils
```

Comment: shaurya@shaurya-linux:~$ sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat exfat-utils
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done    
E: Unable to locate package fuse-exfat

Comment: i was unable to locate the package.. running 16.04

Comment: in 16.04 the package is called exfat-fuse (it's in repos, no need for PPA anymore).. it should be a dependency of exfat-utils anyway, so even if you don't specify it, it will get installed along with utils (it did on my system)

Answer (score 2):

This has now moved. There is no need to add the repository.
The following should be sufficient:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```